# Circular Dependency Calculated Column Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my Calculated Table, variable `AsOfDate` should be reflected by slicer `dim_Date` which is also calculated table.

Calculated table `CrossTableEffectiveDate` derived from table `fact_Premium` that have `Date` relationship to `dim_Date`.

I got error: `Circular Dependency Calculated Column`

```
CrossTableEffectiveDate = 
    VAR AsOfDate = VALUE("2019-01-31") //This value should be based on date value in a slicer
    VAR CrossTables =
        CROSSJOIN(

            SUMMARIZE(fact_Premium, 
                fact_Premium[PolicyNumber],
                fact_Premium[CompanyLocationGuid],
                fact_Premium[Coverage],
                fact_Premium[State],
                fact_Premium[SICCode],
                fact_Premium[ASLOB],
                fact_Premium[ProducerGUID],
                "Start", MIN(fact_Premium[EffectiveDate]),
                "End", MAX(fact_Premium[ExpirationDate]),
                "Premium", SUM(fact_Premium[Premium])
                    ),
            'Calendar')
VAR RiskPeriods =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            FILTER(CrossTables,
                'Calendar'[EoMonth] >= [Start] && 'Calendar'[Month] <= [End] && 'Calendar'[Month] <= AsOfDate),
            "StartRiskMonth", IF([Start] > 'Calendar'[Month], [Start], 'Calendar'[Month]),
            "EndRiskMonth", IF([End] < 'Calendar'[EoMonth], [End], 'Calendar'[EoMonth])
                 )
    RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS(RiskPeriods,
                "PolicyNumber", fact_Premium[PolicyNumber],
                "CompanyLocationGUID", fact_Premium[CompanyLocationGuid],
                "Coverage",fact_Premium[Coverage],
                "State", fact_Premium[State],
                "SICCode",fact_Premium[SICCode],
                "ASLOB", fact_Premium[ASLOB],
                "ProducerGUID",fact_Premium[ProducerGUID],
                "StartRiskMonth", [StartRiskMonth],
                "EndRiskMonth", [EndRiskMonth],
                "YearNum", YEAR('Calendar'[Month]),
                "Qtr", ROUNDUP(MONTH('Calendar'[Month])/3, 0),
                "MonthNum", MONTH('Calendar'[Month]),
                "WrittenPremium", [Premium],
                "DaysInMonth", [EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth] + 1,
                //"EndRiskMonth-Start", [EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth] + 1,
                //"End-Start",[End] - [Start] + 1,
                "EarnedPremium", [Premium] *
                    DIVIDE([EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth] + 1, [End] - [Start] + 1))
```

[image]

How can I make `AsOfDate` variable be referenced by `Date` slicer from `dim_Date`?

Comment: What dependencies does `dim_Date` have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a calculated table or calculated column be dependent on a slicer.

These are only calculated once per data load and are not responsive to any filtering you have in your report.

---

You can add your support to this idea to improve the chances of Microsoft implementing it.

[Dynamic calculated column](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19789756-dynamic-calculated-column)

Comment: Thank you . Hopefully Microsoft will implement it soon.

Comment: I do not think it is still valid what you wrote here. I often create calculated tables like these here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694103/1903793 I use slicers on them. However I ran into problem of circular dependency here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58650531/1903793 I do not know if it is DAX or something else.

Comment: You can certainly use slicers to filter existing calculated tables but you cannot use slicers as part of a calculated table's *definition*.